# CSS: Remove gray highlight on a default option in a select element

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

This problem just happens on IE, tested with IE11.

In order to hide the placeholder in any browser, except IE, the **display none** does the job. However with IE the solution is a lit bit more elaborated. The idea is to make the **default option disabled**, then the user can't click back on the placeholder.

So far so good, but here comes the problem now:

[image]

This shadow + highlight in gray are not desired.

## How to reproduce (Please use IE...)

1. JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lcustodio/u8ng9ybf/4/
2. Stack Snippet:

```css
.default-option {
  display: none;
}
select::-ms-value {
  background: none;
  color: #42413D;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected class='default-option'>Select...</option>
  <option>Hello</option>
  <option>World</option>
</select>
```

*ps: I already remove the blue highlight on the selected option based on this [hint](http://jnelson.in/css/remove-blue-highlighting-select-element-internet-explorer/jacob-nelson). Refer to the css on fiddle as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do anything about that..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it can be done with css,
but you can try with something like that

**example** : [JSFIDDLE](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/WvwqmY)

a little help js

```
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    $('select option.default-option').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm solving this with the other css trick `select::-ms-value {
  background: none;
  color: #42413D;
}` The problem is that there is no event of change on the first time the select is clicked. Something like: .onOpen()...

Comment: Therefore, this `.change` is clever, however doesn't solve the gray highlight issue.